# Infinite loop handling using Events Python Buttons Not Visible

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter, event-handling

I am new to python and have been trying to pause my code by clicking the pause button and resume it as soon as the Resume button is clicked. But the but don't show up during the execution even when I have defined the buttons before the function call. My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

master = Tk()

frame = Frame(master)
frame.grid()

global is_asleep 

def important_function():
    i=0
    while(True):
        print(i)
        i = i+1
        sleep(1)

def pause():
    #pause the execution
    try:
        is_asleep = True
        while(is_asleep):
            sleep(1)
    except:
        print('Error Occured')

def resume():
    is_asleep = False

def stop():
    #stop the execution
    try:
        print('Stop')
        exit()
    except:
        print('Error Occured')

pause = Button(frame, text = "Pause", command = pause).grid()
stop = Button(frame, text = "Stop", command = stop).grid()
resume = Button(frame, text = "Resume", command = resume).grid()

important_function()

master.mainloop()
```

Please help me understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: Looks like you're going to get stuck in the while loop inside `important_function` and never reach `master.mainloop()`. Does any window appear at all or just no buttons?

Comment: Just no window nor any button appears.@busybear

Comment: You'll need to execute `master.mainloop()` in order for you GUI to work/appear. I would suggest looking up how tkinter works if it's not apparent why this has to happen. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `important_function` but using `after` might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method

Comment: Hey thanks @busybear! 
I did this: 

`pause = Button(master, text = "Pause", command = pause).grid() \n

stop = Button(master, text = "Stop", command = stop).grid()\n

resume = Button(master, text = "Resume", command = resume).grid() \n

master.after(100,important_function) \n
 
master.mainloop()`

And it seems to help me display the buttons!

Comment: `sleep` does exactly what it says: it puts the whole application to sleep. That means it can't process events, refresh the screen, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues :**
infinite while loop `important_function()` which is blocking the call of `master.mainloop()`

**Fix :**
I have added the fixed `while(true)` call and simplified the code for you.
running infinite loop on a thread and pausing and resuming based on events of button clicks .

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import threading

master = Tk()

global is_asleep


def important_function(e):
    i = 0

    while (True):
        event_is_set = pauseEvent.wait()
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
        sleep(1)


def pause():
    # pause the execution
    # e.wait()
    pauseEvent.clear()


def resume():
    pauseEvent.set()


def stop():
    # stop the execution
    try:
        print('Stop')
        pauseEvent.clear()
        master.quit()
        sys.exit("some error message")
    except:
        print('Error Occured')


pauseButton = Button(master, text="Pause", command=pause)
pauseButton.pack()
stopButton = Button(master, text="Stop", command=stop)
stopButton.pack()
resumeButtom = Button(master, text="Resume", command=resume)
resumeButtom.pack()

pauseEvent = threading.Event()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=important_function,
                      args=(pauseEvent,))
t1.daemon =  True
t1.start()
pauseEvent.set()
mainloop()
```

Comment: So what I was trying to simulate was to pause and resume an infinite code with my script. Please help me in implementing that.

Comment: I have updated the answer please accept if that is what you needed.